# Unable to write data into xlsx file in python using openpyxl

Tags: python, python-3.x, openpyxl

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here.It always throws an error. I want to achieve to write test data strings inside B4 cell in the existing excel file.

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
template_wb = load_workbook(r'E:\test.xlsx')
template_ws= template_wb.sheetnames[0]
template_ws['B4']='test data'
template_wb.save()
template_wb.close()
```

Error:

template_ws['B4']='test data'
TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment

Comment: What do you tink `template_ws` is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It must be `worksheets` not the `sheetnames`:

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

template_wb = load_workbook(r'E:\test.xlsx')
template_ws= template_wb.worksheets[0]
template_ws['B4']='test data'
template_wb.save("E:\test.xlsx")
template_wb.close()
```